# Fetch worklog results of a particular user

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I want to get the total hours that every user has logged in, in a specific project every week.

In order to achieve this, I'm trying to get the whole worklog in the project, and then filter it by the worklog Author. This is the query I'm using:

```
https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/search?startIndex=0&maxResults=100&jql=project=%27Test%20Project%27+and+worklogAuthor=testUser+and+updated%3E=-7d&fields=worklog
```

This brings back every issue that has been updated in the last 7 days, and the user is related to it. However, it also brings back the worklog of another user that has added time in the same issue for example.

**My question is the following**, is there a way to filter the query by name, and bring back the worklog of a particular user, without the worklogs of other users that are simply related to the same issue?

The query returns the results in a json format that look like this for every worklog of a user:

```
"worklogs": [
{
"author": {...}, // 8 items, where there's a 'name' field for the particular user
"updateAuthor": {...}, // 8 items
"comment": "",
"created": "2018-01-03T13:42:15.000+0200",
"updated": "2018-01-03T13:42:15.000+0200",
"started": "2018-01-03T13:42:00.000+0200",
"timeSpent": "1h",
"timeSpentSeconds": 3600,
"id": "10540",
"issueId": "10674"
},
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible with jira out of the box. The jira rest api only supports retrieving work logs for issues, not users.

However, there are add-ons like [Script Runner](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview) that provide additional JQL functions that allow you to query for issues where a specific user has logged work. You can easily execute such a JQL using the [search REST API](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/?_ga=2.39136163.1468957549.1515487536-395998871.1515487536#api/2/search). This will give you a smaller list of issues/work logs to filter on.

Example JQL:

```
issueFunction in workLogged(on "2015/07/28" by admin)
```

More info about custom jql functions is available in the Script Runner [documentation](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/jql-functions.html#_worklogged).

Answer (score 0):

```
worklogAuthor = currentUser()
```

or

```
worklogAuthor = marc
```

might help you